# Transferring backend files to compute engine from remote workstation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, file-transfer, scp, cp

I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-compute-engine#java) quickstart for deploying a simple java web app on Compute engine running Debian os. I am facing difficulty in understanding the commands used for transferring files from a remote workstation to compute engine instance. Can someone with example elaborate how to use these

```
gcloud compute scp --scp-flag=-pr ../../endpoints [INSTANCE-NAME]:~/
  gcloud compute scp ../../pom.xml [INSTANCE-NAME]:~/
```

commands to transfer web app files from my desktop to compute engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send information from your local machine to a VM:

```
$ gcloud compute scp <local-path-to-file> vm:<path-to-dir> --zone <instance-zone>
```

So for example, if you want to copy a local file named my-local-file in your current directory, to a remote VM named my-vm-1 in zone us-east1-b and put the file inside the folder /home/user-me, you would do:

gcloud compute scp ./my-local-file my-vm-1:/home/user-me --zone us-east1-b

You can use the --recurse option for directories as follows:

gcloud compute scp --recurse ./my-local-file my-vm-1:/home/user-me --zone us-east1-b

The ssh keys will propagate and the status about the transfer progress is displayed on the terminal window.

Comment: And if I need to transfer a directory containing many files and subsequent folders containing a number of files as in case of a web app, then how this command should be modified ?

Comment: You can use the --recurse option for directories as follows:

gcloud compute scp --recurse ./my-local-file my-vm-1:/home/user-me       --zone us-east1-b

Comment: Oh yeah !! I got it. Thank you.